# How to deserialize byte[] into generic object to be cast at method call

Tags: c#, object, serialization, dynamic, aes

I am working on an object encryption class. I have everything worked out but I want to be able to encrypt/decrypt any object type with one deserialize method. As of now the only thing holding me up is the deserialize method. I have the function returning type(object) in the hopes of returning a weak typed object. It works as long as I cast the type during the return value assignment, but If I deserialize into type 'object' the result is byte[].

This means that I have to write a deserialize method for every object(T) i want to operate on. What I want to do is pass Type(T) as a parameter to the deserialize method so I can deserialize into object(T), then return the typed object.

The problem is that using a typed parameter is apparently not allowed. 

If I do `obj = (type.GetType())br.Deserialize(ms);`
I get `; expected` between '(object(T)) and br.'.

If I do `obj = (br.Deserialize(ms) as type);` I get `The type of namespace "type" could not be found. (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

or I get a symbol can not be resolved error. 
Any help is appreciated. Full code is below.

```
        private byte[] serialize(object param)
    {
        byte[] encMsg = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            IFormatter br = new BinaryFormatter();
            br.Serialize(ms, param);
            encMsg = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return encMsg;
    }

    private object deserialize(byte[] param)
    {
        object obj = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(param))
        {
            IFormatter br = new BinaryFormatter();
            obj = (br.Deserialize(ms) as myObject);
        }

        return obj;
    }

    private byte[] encrypt(byte[] param)
    {
        byte[] encMsg = null;
        using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
        {
            myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.ANSIX923;
            ICryptoTransform autoBot = myAes.CreateEncryptor(myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, autoBot, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(param, 0, (int)param.Length);
                }
                encMsg = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return encMsg;
    }

    private byte[] decrypt(byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] param)
    {
        byte[] dcparam = null;
        using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
        {
            myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.ANSIX923;
            ICryptoTransform autoBot = myAes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, autoBot, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(param, 0, (int)param.Length);
                }
                dcparam = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return dcparam;
    }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The type you want to deserialize must be known at compile time.. So your method can be like:

```
private T Deserialize<T>(byte[] param)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(param))
    {
        IFormatter br = new BinaryFormatter();
        return (T)br.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like

```
var myclass = Deserialize<MyClass>(buf);
```

Comment: You're missing the <T> from the method signature.

Comment: @JamieSee technically it's not required on the method if your class already has the type parameter - in fact it will generate a compiler warning.  But OP did say he wanted it on the method :)

Comment: My notifications are going to spam. That worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: In .NET 5, the method `new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms)` is deprecated because is unsecure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide

Answer (score 1):

Since `BinaryFormatter` is depricated in .NET 5 +
you could use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` or `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` in combination with **NewtonsoftJson** to serialize and deserialize objects.

### Serialization

```
byte[] serializedObject = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject));
```

### Deserialization

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeof(myObject)>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply utilize the type parameter of your class.

By trying to dynamically do a GetType or a cast, you're forcing a runtime evaluation, rather than using generics to create a compile-time referenced version.

The type parameter will compile a separate version of your class that is strongly typed for every parameter type T that is encounted by the compiler.  So T is actually a placeholder for a strong reference.

```
obj = (br.Deserialize(ms) as T);
```